# índice y nombre al exportar un cuaderno Jupyter a PDF con nbconvert

Tags: python, jupyter

3 preguntas sobre exportar cuadernos jupyter a pdf con nbconvert

1. Alguien sabe como generar un índice automático en un cuaderno Jupyter al exportarlo como PDF con nbconvert?
2. ALguien sabe como incorporar nombre del autor en un cuaderno Jupyter al exportarlo como PDF con nbconvert?
3. Alguien sabe como insertar saltos de página en un cuaderno Jupyter al exportarlo como PDF con nbconvert?

Gracias

Comment: Sin conocer mucho, sospecho que ambas preguntas pueden resolverse usando templates que definas y luego uses al exportar

Comment: Como se definen templates?

Comment: No lo he hecho ni usado, pero veo en la [documentación](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) que hay algunos ejemplos. Disculpa no ser de más ayuda